# How to choose K objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

You are given a list of numbers. Ex. : 1, 1, 2, 3
How many ways can you choose  3 numbers from here so that each number is taken only once?
[ 1, 2, 3 can be made in 2 ways. So the answer of is 2][If we have to choose 2 numbers we can do that in 5 ways. 1-2 --> 2 ways, 1-3 --> 2 ways and 2-3 --> 1 way. So the ans is 5]
But, can it be generalized?
For expamle, if the ques is

> you are given $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3},b_{1},b_{2},...$ how many ways can
>   you choose $k$ numbers from that so that every number is dintinct?

Any hints will be apreciated.

Comment: Shows resemblance with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1461012/75923)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: @drhab i can't understand the solution. Can you explain it when the list is 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 and k is 3?

Comment: There are $\binom52=10$ possibilities if it comes to choosing the numbers: $123$,$124$,$125$,$134$,$135$,$145$,$234$,$235$,$245$ and $345$. For each of them we find a number of possibilities. E.g. for option $123$ we find $3\times2\times1=6$ possibilities and for $234$ we find $2\times1\times1=2$ possibilities. The sum of these $10$ numbers is the answer.

Comment: @drhab i actually found that solution before posting. i was looking for a solution that would require less calculation. and thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your search for such solution, but I suspect it will be in vain. Let's hope I am wrong ;).