# How to choose n elements from m when certain elements can't be taken together?

Tags: combinatorics

Say we are given some elements

$a_1,a_2,...,a_x,b_1,b_2,...,b_y,...$ and so on.

The total elements given are $m$ and we have to choose $n$ elements from them. The condition is that no two elements from the same group(a,b,...) can be taken together.

This can be computed easily if n is small.
For n = 2,

total combinations = $^{number of groups}C_2$

But if n is bigger, say n = 4, computing it manually is a very tedious task.

So, what I want to ask is that is there any general formula for it ?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1461012/75923). The [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1461390/75923) to it might be what you are searching for.